# Duplicate values Conditional selection PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with thousands of entries

"id" is the primary key

"event_description"

"event_time"

"location"

In a php script i need to select all rows from the table and if "locationXXX" appears in more than one row collect the various values for "event_description" paired with respective "event_time" and echo them as list items

if instead there are no duplicates then select it normally and echo the results

Altering table structure is an option but i'd rather not

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What does "echo it normally" mean? Why not just make them a list of one element, so you can display singletons and duplicates the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is called `event`

```
SELECT location, event_description, event_time
FROM event
GROUP BY location
HAVING COUNT(location) > 1;
```

Comment: ps. It's preferred that if you ask a question on StackOverflow, you should attempt to come up with a solution yourself i.e. `what have you tried?`, before asking for one, but I knew what the answer was, so here it is :)